# how extract a part of "strings" android

Tags: java, android, lexical-analysis

I have been trying to extract "Near Gangotri hospital" and "no 125/6 8th Miles Bus Stop" but i was not able to extract it can any one please help me to extract the string

I need to extract 3 rd string which is after 2 nd Pipe(|) operator.

```
9649|14:30|Near Gangotri hospital |Opp Central Bank (Test)|9880955077|B T M Layout ~ 8937|14:34|no 125/6 8th Miles Bus Stop|Near 8th Mile Signal|080 65468012222|8th Mile
```

Comment: have you tried the substring method? like string.substring(11,32); See if that gives you the Near Gangotri hospital. Might have to play with the positions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`String.split(String regex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) to split your text and later choose parts you wanted.

```
String text = "9649|14:30|Near Gangotri hospital |Opp Central Bank (Test)|9880955077|B T M Layout ~ 8937|14:34|no 125/6 8th Miles Bus Stop|Near 8th Mile Signal|080 65468012222|8th Mile";
String parts[] = text.split("|");
String part3 = parts[2]; //Near Gangotri hospital
```

Comment: I am pretty sure you cannot do `text.split("|");` as the pipe is a special character in regex. I think you will need to do `text.split( Pattern.quote( "|" ) );`

Comment: String parts[] = text.split("\\|");